# Add to class if element matches div width

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm looking for the best way to have a class added to an img tag if the width of the image is smaller than the section element.

```
<section>
<img>
</section>

section {
   width:700px
}
```

I tried the following with no such luck:

```
var image = $('img');
var width = $('section').width();

if (width < 700) {
image.addClass('classname');
```

any help would be great guys :)

Comment: you're referencing "img" at `img.addClass` but the reference variable is `image`

Comment: `jQuery(function($) { /* code here will wait for the DOM content to be ready */ })`

Comment: Thanks Chris, still no luck though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment you are trying to add the class to "img" which is undefined. Either switch that out so you have

```
image.addClass('classname')
```

Or since it's a short selector just insert that

```
$('img').addClass('classname')
```

Also make sure that the jQuery call is being made within a `$(document).ready(...)` call

Comment: Or: [`$('img').toggleClass('classname', $('section').width() < 700);`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: Sorry I had used the var 'image'.  Is there anything else there that would prevent this from working?

Comment: No. That did it.  Thanks Chris